# Get array from a JSON file by parsing the array name in the url

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON file:

alldata.json

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "name": "Marcos Alonso",
        "position": "Left-Back",
        "nationality": "Spain",
        "marketValue": "9,000,000 €",
        "created": "2017-04-15 10:04:58"
    }],

"articles": [
{
    "author": "Stephen Walter",
    "title": "Disruptive stag party revellers thrown off plane at Manchester Airport",
    "url": "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/04/15/disruptive-stag-party-revellers-thrown-plane-manchester-airport/",
    "publishedAt": "2017-04-15T09:25:10Z"
}],

"land": [
{
    "state": "Somewhr",
    "found": "1889",
    "area": "6,812",
    "empl": "1,325",
    "ppl": "16,842"

}]
}
```

Then I have this php file:

getSeacrh.php

```
$url = ('alldata.json');
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$mySearch = $_GET['search']; //to get array that I want
if (!$mySearch) {
    echo 'No search';
} else {
    //I would need help here
    foreach ($data as $value) { //what can I do here to get just only searched array 
        $srch = $value[$mySearch]; //and not all arrays in the json file?
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $json_string = json_encode($temp, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print $json_string;
}
```

Kindly help me on what to do so that when I execute my php file (getSearch.php), e.g "http://localhost/test/getsearch.php?search=players" I will get just the "players" array. Also if I parse other array names in the file it will give me just that array. Below is an example of what I meant:

```
 {
    "players": [
        {
            "name": "Marcos Alonso",
            "position": "Left-Back",
            "nationality": "Spain",
            "marketValue": "9,000,000 €",
            "created": "2017-04-15 10:04:58"
        }]
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to just return the 1st level key from your JSON file, then you can do this by referencing the key you need on the array of data.

```
if (!$mySearch) {
    echo 'No search';
} else {
    //I would need help here
    $temp = array($mySearch => $data[$mySearch]);
    //$temp is now an array with a key that is the key given by the user,
    //and the value of that key is the data from the $data variable

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    $json_string = json_encode($temp, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print $json_string;
}
```

One caveat to keep in mind is that someone may provide a key that doesn't exist in your data array, and this will throw an error. As a result, make sure your conditional tests that not only that a key is given by the user, but that it exists in your data.

```
if (!$mySearch) {
    echo 'No search';
} elseif (empty($data[$mySearch])) {
    //Handle this error here
} else {
    ...
}
```